# REGEX: Remove string IF string is between two special characters and if the string contains a specific substring

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a Regex expression that would allow me to perform two match two conditions at the same time.
I want to remove any string that is contained between two special characters IF the string includes at least one of these substrings: ".jpeg" ".png".

For instance, given the following text:

`I like ice-cream very much! Oh me too!  !be148b3b3992a514839e5d9a3c9b80bf--lego-stormtrooper-stormtroopers (1) (1).jpeg|width=474,height=273!`

The expected result should be: `I like ice-cream very much! Oh me too!`

I found this Regex `!.*?!` that works to remove anything between the `!` but this would remove also the text `Oh me too`

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Try `![^!]*\.(?:jpeg|png)[^!]*!` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6PBrb/2)) or  `![^\s!][^!]*\.(?:jpeg|png)[^!]*!` if the first char after a qualifying `!` must not be a whitespace ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6PBrb/1)).

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew, huge thanks, it works like a charm!

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew do you have a solution that includes also the "."? So it would check for ".jpeg" or ".png" instead of "jpeg" or "png"

Comment: There is a `\.` in both patterns, I have explained that in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
![^!]*\.(?:jpeg|png)[^!]*!
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6PBrb/2). It matches

- `!` - a `!` char
- `[^!]*` - zero or more chars other than `!`
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `(?:jpeg|png)` - `jpeg` or `png`
- `[^!]*` - zero or more chars other than `!`
- `!` - a `!` char

```
!(?!\s)[^!]*\.(?:jpeg|png)[^!]*!
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6PBrb/3). *Details*:

- `!` - a `!` char
- `(?!\s)` - right after the first `!` there should be no whitespace
- `[^!]*` - zero or more chars other than `!`
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `(?:jpeg|png)` - `jpeg` or `png`
- `[^!]*` - zero or more chars other than `!`
- `!` - a `!` char

**NOTE**: to also match `jpg`, replace `jpeg` with `jpe?g` in the pattern you chose.